# Angular, comparing 2 objects and replacing (possibly concatinating?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have 2 multi-select lists in angular that are dependent on on another. One is the parent list and one is the child list. When landing, there is nothing in the child list and once you select (one or many) items from the parent multi-select, it will then populate the child list with the children of the selected item(s) from the parent list. This works great - just for reference I have a $watch on the parent model, so when it changes (the user selects something in the parent list - it will then call an $http and fetch the results for the children list

like so  -

```
$scope.$watch('selectedResources', function (newValue) {
angular.forEach($scope.selectedResources, function(data){
                $scope.generalIDArray.push(data.id);
            });
            //id's = $scope.imageIDArray
            //place new data in $scope.imageOptionsSub
            $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/listSubCategories',
                    data: {
                        page: 0,
                        ids: $scope.generalIDArray
                    }
                })
            .success(function(data){
                //empty options
                $scope.resourceOptionsSub = [];
                //push new data in
                angular.forEach(data.subCategories, function(index) {
                    $scope.resourceOptionsSub.push(index);
                });
            });
```

So - I push all the id's in and send them to get the results back.

However - here is my problem. I realized after trying this out that I don't want to completely replace resourceOptionsSub with all the new results, because the user has interacted with the child results - they have a .checked value on them that means the user has selected them, this will be wiped out and refreshed each time I make a new call because it empties out the scope and replaces it, even if it is the same items.

What I would like to happen is to kind of compare if there are items that already exist in resourceOptionsSub that are coming in with the call, and sort of keep the original resourceOptionsSub  and compare it to the new one coming in, and maybe pull off the items that don't exist any more?

I'm thinking I should somehow compare the 2 objects 1  being the original, 2 being the new - and if 2 has anything 1 does not have, then pull it out of 1, because then I could keep the items that are the same untouched. If anyone could point me in the right direction here as to where to look I would much appreciate it, as I am at a bit of a loss as to how to handle this. Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

angular.extend will work but you will need start with an empty object like so:

```
var updatedObj = angular.extend({}, obj1, obj2);
```

Comment: Angular always amazes me with how simple is makes things, thank you!